# Tal igual ou tal e qual?

Tags: expressões, expressões-idiomáticas

Existe uma expressão usada no português usada para expressar a semelhança de duas coisas. Mas estou com dúvida se essa expressão é "tal e qual" ou "tal igual", pois pelo menos eu já pronunciei das duas formas.

e qual -> iqual -> igual

Vejam os seguintes exemplos (vou usar sempre tal e qual):

> O menino tem uma cara tal e qual á do pai.
>
> Vi uma gata tal e qual á que tenho na minha casa
>
> Trouxe o cortinado, era este? Sim, tal e qual.
>
> O Artur tem uma atitude tal e qual á do pai

Também pode ser usada para expressar alguma ironia.

> Depois de jantar vamos ao cinema.
>
> Sim, claro, tal e qual! Não vês que a gente tem que poupar dinheiro!?

Como é que a expressão deve ser escrita, posso usar ambas as variantes?

Comment: Nunca tinha ouvido antes "tal igual", apenas "tal e qual"

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Nem eu, mas, se você procurar nas redes sociais, verá algumas centenas de resultados. O problema é que estes meios são conhecidos justamente por serem bastante caóticos. De repente, pode ser um meme e nós somos os "tiozões" que estamos "por fora".

Comment: Hum pois concordo, e redes sociais dificilmente constituem boas fontes para exemplos de correcto uso da linguagem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Tal e qual](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/tal) é a forma dicionarizada, e também a variação mais popular. Parece-me a grafia mais adequada.

*Tal igual*, com este sentido, não é dicionarizada, e também não encontrei nenhum registro intencional desta variação.

Answer (score 4):

**"tal qual"**, da mesma forma que "tal e qual", também é encontrada em dicionários e **é a forma que mais ouço em pt-BR.**

> - "tal qual" - exatamente o mesmo, sem nenhuma diferença, do mesmo modo que.
> - "tal e qual" - V. tal qual. --- *Novo Dicionário Aurélio, 2ª edição, Editora Nova Fronteira.*
>
> Copiou o vestido da amiga, tal qual.
>
> Eu quisera viver tal qual os passarinhos.
>
> Ele fala tal qual o pai.

ps  "tal igual" makes no sense.